# How to create a numlist of repeated values in Stata

Tags: stata

I have two local values: `a` and `b`. I require a numlist that contains `b` copies of `a`. Neither of the below work (the first one I think I understand, but I don't understand the second, since I thought the `display` extended macro function took care of all the processing of the `smcl`).

```
. numlist "{dup `b':`a'}"
invalid numlist

. local x: display "{dup `b':`a'}"
. numlist "`x'"
invalid numlist
```

How can I create a numlist of `b` replications of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` supports a `_dup()` syntax but the underscore is essential and any curly brackets (braces) are either superfluous or a source of difficulty. That is closer to some SMCL syntax but quite distinct from it.

You can also use the SMCL syntax.

Here is some technique:

This first pair of examples shows that we need to duplicate a closing (or leading) space as well as any desired text; otherwise we don't get what we want.

```
. di _dup(10) "42 "
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 

. di _dup(10) "42"
42424242424242424242
```

We can also put the result in a local macro. Fortunately. if we parse it uninformative spaces will be ignored. Please note that in my case, and in yours too, `macro list` will also show other stuff not relevant to the question.

```
. local wanted : di _dup(10) "42 "

. di "`wanted'"
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 

. tokenize "`wanted'"

. mac li
_10:            42
_9:             42
_8:             42
_7:             42
_6:             42
_5:             42
_4:             42
_3:             42
_2:             42
_1:             42
_wanted:        42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
```

This also works:

```
. di "{dup 10:42 }"
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 

. local wanted : di "{dup 10:42 }"

. di "`wanted'"
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
```

This still leaves the question of what was wrong with the original syntax using `numlist`. My interpretation is that `numlist` just doesn't understand SMCL directives, and that work-arounds to hide the SMCL are not easier than any of the solutions here. There is no reason to use `numlist` any way, as duplication of elements can be achieved otherwise.

Comment: Nick, always instructive! But you wrote "There is no reason to use numlist any way, as duplication of elements can be achieved otherwise." and I do not simply want duplicates, but *duplicates specifically in a numlist*.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see what difference that makes.

Comment: If I am trying to transform input of a single number within the context of a program option, into a duplicate based on other information supplied by the caller of the program then my program can then itself call other programs that expect a numlist, and choke on examples the the ones I gave. :)

Comment: Sounds like another question.

Comment: Nick, can you elucidate that last comment? I am pretty sure that my original question precisely asked for creating numlists with duplicate values (given some input values), but perhaps I am not understanding your last comment? :) If there's a good new question to add, I am happy to add it.

Comment: Put it this way: you seem to think that part of your question remains unanswered; if so, then I don't understand what else you are asking, so please flesh it out,

Comment: I think that Alexis believes that a `numlist` is some sort of storage construct, like a scalar or a matrix or a local macro, and that the use of the `numlist` command somehow creates a `numlist` construct. But this is not so. `help numlist` shows us that a `numlist` is a syntactic construct, not a storage construct, and `help nlist` shows us that the numlist command expands shorthand numlists and stores the result in the macro `r(numlist)` - in other words, as text consisting of a list of space-separated numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by the phrase "numlist that contains b copies of a" you mean: you have some local macro `a` which you would like to copy `b` times and store the output as a list (another local macro).

Here is an example with numeric `a` ...

```
local a = 4
local b = 6
local c 
forval i = 1/`b' {
  local c `c' `a'
}
di "`c'"

4 4 4 4 4 4
```

... and string `a` :

```
local a = "copy_me!"
local b = 6
local c = ""
forval i = 1/`b' {
  local c `c' `a'
}
di "`c'"

copy_me! copy_me! copy_me! copy_me! copy_me! copy_me!
```

A perfect material on almost any basic thing in Stata including working with local macros: [A little bit of Stata programming goes along way (by CF Baum)](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/wp612.pdf) (page 5 for your case).

Comment: I'd emphasise with Andrey that his looping style is cleaner than in the question  --  and in older versions of Stata less likely to run into length limits than explicit string evaluation with `=` and `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, taking yet another stab at this, this seems to work:

```
. local c = ""
. forvalues i = 1/`b' { 
.  local c = "`c'" + " `a'"
.  }
. numlist "`c'"
```

**I am still interested in others' answers.**

Comment: Stray character `l` in middle line?

Comment: @NickCox [BLUSH!]